# Console saying that array is [Array(0)] when trying to log

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to filter an array multiple times, but i am encountering a problem.
[Console message 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhAAc.png)

And when i open up the [[Prototype]], this comes up [Console message 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAXlC.png)

JavaScript:

```
  async function testFunction(arrayRange, arrayTheta, url, graphLabels, mcsArray, channelArray, caseArray, caseData) {

//Gets data from the JSON-file, were the url is the box that is checked
const response = await fetch(url);
const productData = await response.json();

//result is what will come out
const result = [];

/*The for-loop under is used to check every index in the array, and the reason for that is because it is needed to check for everything in the array.
Otherwise it will only check caseArray[0].*/
for (let index = 0; index < caseArray.length; index++) { //This loop is for caseArray
  if (caseArray[index] == "Boresight-Boresight") {
    console.log("Boresight-Boresight / checked")
    //The line under will filter everything inside of product data by checking if the Case-variable is "that value". Then push it into the result array.
    result.push(productData.filter(x => x.Case === "Boresight-Boresight")); //Pushing data into array
  } 
  if (caseArray[index] == "Omni-Boresight") {
    console.log("Omni-Boresight / checked")
    result.push(productData.filter(x => x.Case === "Omni-Boresight"));
  } 
  if (caseArray[index] == "Omni-Maxscan") {
    console.log("Omni-Maxscan / checked")
    result.push(productData.filter(x => x.Case === "Omni-Maxscan"));
  } 
  if (caseArray[index] == "Maxscan-Maxscan") {
    console.log("Maxscan-Maxscan / checked")
    result.push(productData.filter(x => x.Case === "Maxscan-Maxscan"));
  }
}
console.log(result)


for (let index = 0; index < mcsArray.length; index++) { //This loop is for mcsArray
  if (mcsArray[index] == 0) {
    console.log(0)
    result.push(result.filter(x => x.mcs === 0));
  }
  if (mcsArray[index] == 1) {
    console.log(1)
    result.push(result.filter(x => x.mcs === 1));
  }
  if (mcsArray[index] == 2) {
    console.log(2)
    result.push(result.filter(x => x.mcs === 2));
  }
  if (mcsArray[index] == 3) {
    console.log(3)
    result.push(result.filter(x => x.mcs === 3));
  }
  if (mcsArray[index] == 4) {
    console.log(4)
    result.push(result.filter(x => x.mcs === 4));
  }
  if (mcsArray[index] == 5) {
    console.log(5)
    result.push(result.filter(x => x.mcs === 5));
  }
  if (mcsArray[index] == 6) {
    console.log(6)
    result.push(result.filter(x => x.mcs === 6));
  }
  if (mcsArray[index] == 7) {
    console.log(7)
    result.push(result.filter(x => x.mcs === 7));
  }
  if (mcsArray[index] == 8) {
    console.log(8)
    result.push(result.filter(x => x.mcs === 8));
  }
  if (mcsArray[index] == 9) {
    console.log(9)
    result.push(result.filter(x => x.mcs === 9));
  }
  if (mcsArray[index] == 10) {
    console.log(10)
    result.push(result.filter(x => x.mcs === 10));
  }
  if (mcsArray[index] == 11) {
    console.log(11)
    result.push(result.filter(x => x.mcs === 11));
  }
  if (mcsArray[index] == 12) {
    console.log(12)
    result.push(result.filter(x => x.mcs === 12));
  }

}

console.log(result)
```

The problem occures when i try to filter the mcs in result, but when i filter Case, there is no problems.

If you can help, thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `filter`? I mean, you iterate your arrays using a `for` loop, it means everytime you find a match within your `if`s you already have that element, and yet you filter the entire array again to extract the current element... `result.push(result.filter(x => x.mcs === 0));` wouldn't it be `result.push( result[index] )`?

Comment: @GrafiCode I can try to explain what i am trying to do. So, when i get the first result i have the json-file filtered once where for example only the elements that contain a case variable with the value "Boresight-Boresight". And after that i am trying to filter the mcs-variable in the elements from the first result. 

For example:
I want all elements with "Boresight-Boresight" and then from all the does elements i want the mcs to be 1. And then get dose elements.

Is that understandable?
(also sorry for the late responce, i do not get notifications for some reason)